# Is there way to get Visual Studio environment variable in SQL seeding script?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Is there way to access [visual studio environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) such as $(SolutionDir) in T-sql seeding script? Basically, I have a set of seeding script, but I try to avoid reference the hard-code path such as C:\projects**\seeding.sql, instead , I want to use $(SolutionDir)Seeding.sql

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: What happens when your project is run outside Visual Studio, where those variables don't exist? (Or by a user who wouldn't have VS at all?) Wouldn't it be better to base the location somewhere related to your application's location instead?

Comment: That should work, as long as I don't have hardcode the physical path.

Comment: What should work? Using environmental variables that don't exist? Or using a location based on your application's location? (When you post a comment to a specific person, use @UserName, where "UserName" is the person to whom you're responding so that they're notified. You get notified automatically because the comment is to your question.)

Comment: Hi, Ken, thanks for the input, using the location based on application's location work. As a non-native speaker, sometimes,I do struggle experessing myself clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the general process for using project variables in SQL in your database project from MSDN:

[How to: Define Variables for Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386162(v=vs.90).aspx)

This depends on what version of Visual Studio you're using (and whether you're using a database project -- highly recommended), but the general idea is you can assign some of your project variables as SQLCMD variables, build a SQLCMD script using those variables and when you run a build, the system will use SQLCMD to invoke your script, applying the variables as necessary to run your script.

Even more to the point, the database project's recommended practice for "seeding" scripts and other post-build artifacts is to designate one SQL script as the post-build script and have it use SQLCMD syntax to invoke other .sql script files.

So in my project (for example) I have this SQL script in a Scripts folder:

```
:r .\PopulateNumbersTable.sql
:r .\Insert.Dimension.Date.sql
:r .\FillInMetaData.sql
:r .\Permissions.sql
```

Which then calls each of those scripts (also in the folder using relative paths) which are run in SQLCMD mode. So in PopulateNumbersTable.sql for example, I set the max value of the numbers table as a SQLCMD variable so when the script runs in the post-build it uses that value.

Anyway, check out SQLCMD and VS Database Projects, it basically covers what you're looking for, it's plenty flexible and (for me) pretty easy to understand.